# Why do we get 'cannot open file' we use XSendFile with /tmp?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

We're upgrading to Fedora 18.  We've deployed our Rails app, and it works as expected, *except* for downloading zip files of reports.  It works on our existing production server (Fedora 15).

We're using `XSendFile` to send the zip files.  It doesn't work when the files are located in `/tmp`, but it works in other circumstances.

### Details

The zip files are generated using `Tempfile.open` in Ruby, which creates a file in `/tmp` by default.  However, Apache gives us a 404 and an error like this in `error_log`:

```
[Thu May 02 11:33:18.010388 2013] [:error] [pid ...] (2)No such file or directory: [client ...] xsendfile: cannot open file: /tmp/..., referer: https://...
```

The first thing we checked is our configuration.  This is what we have:

```
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /tmp
```

That seems to be correct [given the docs](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) -- `/tmp` is even used in the example.

We started trying to narrow down the problem.  We started forcing the Rails app to serve other files by hardcoding the path.  Each time, we'd change the directory for `XSendFilePath` in the Apache config and the file path used in the Rails app.

Results:

```
fails: /tmp/hello.zip
works: /var/www/html/rails_production/current/public/hello.zip
works: /home/capistrano/hello2.zip
fails: /tmp/test-xsendfile/hello3.zip
works: /tmp2/hello4.zip
```

In the failing cases, the permissions were set to 777 apache:apache, which would seem liberal enough.  The working cases didn't require those permissions, though.

Because we are suspecting the `/tmp` path to be the issue, we made `/tmp2` with the same permissions and ownership (`drwxrwxrwt.` and `root:root`).  The SELinux context for `/tmp2` was changed to be identical using `chcon`.

Even with those changes, `XSendFile` **works** with `/tmp2`.  That makes the problem seem to be an Apache config issue.  We can work around this, but we'd prefer not to.

What are we missing that lets `/tmp2` work, but not `/tmp`?

### Versions

- Apache 2.4.4
- `mod_xsendfile` 0.12 (RPM from Fedora 18, not something we compiled)

NOTE: We're using `mod_security`, but it isn't in enforcing mode.

Comment: I don't know XSendFile but maybe `777` is too liberal? Was it `777` in `/tmp2`, too? You may attach to apache with strace (`strace -p $PID -f -e trace=file`) to get a better understanding of what happens at the system level.

Comment: In don't know why only /tmp/ doesn't work, but you shouldn't use Tempfile with XSendFile. Tempfile unlinks the file as soon as it's garbage collected, so XSendFile may not have the chance to grab the file before it's removed. You should use regular File to create the temporary file.

Comment: @Lie That's definitely a possible race condition.  I think `Tempfile` may have been used for convenience.  Ideally, we could use `X-SendFile-Temporary`, but that feature hasn't been released yet.  https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/beta/

Comment: Yes, `X-SendFile-Temporary` would be great when it's released, but for the moment you should just run a cron job to delete old temporaries. Also, I presume that opening regular File also still give you the same issue on /tmp/?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same issue with `/tmp`.  Thanks for your input, I think this is about the route we'll be taking...